# How to have tabs at the bottom while using action bar sherlock?

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I am working on an app where I am using [ActionbarSherLock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/).

As per the requirements I want the Tabs at bottom,
but by default tabs appears at the top.

How I can set the tabs at the bottom...

Comment: Your requirements are flawed: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html (see "Don't use bottom tab bars")

Comment: Yes I know that....but still if I want to this how can I do ????